# Pen mouse messages are suppressed when pen is positioned on a button (in WndProc method). How to fix this?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, wndproc, pen

I want to keep track of the pen's position from anywhere. I want WndProc to be called even if it's on the button. But, If there is a button in the form, wndProc does not occur. What should I do?

**Some details:**

Certain pen mouse message comes in wndProc's message. (pen mouse message's Msg is 0x0711)

If I move the pen inside the form, the value continues to come up with wndProc.
But, If there is a button in the form, wndProc does not occur on a button.

```
public const int PEN = 0x0711;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (PEN == m.Msg)
    {
       // TODO: function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not tested as I do not have a Pen, but in principle it the concept should work.

Use an [IMessageFilter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=netframework-4.8) implementation to detect the PEN message being sent to the form or one of its child controls and execute the desired function.

```
class PenFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private const int PEN = 0x0711;
    private readonly Form parent;
    public PenFilter(Form parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        Control targetControl = Control.FromChildHandle(m.HWnd);
        if (targetControl != null && (targetControl == parent || parent == targetControl.FindForm()))
        {
            // execute your function
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Install/remove the filter based on form activation/deactivation.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private PenFilter penFilter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        penFilter = new PenFilter(this);
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(penFilter);
        base.OnActivated(e);
    }
    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(penFilter);
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
    }
}
```